# Can I create a secondary index on a UDT field in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, secondary-indexes

I have a table with a UDT that stores a user address. Can I index on the country code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondary indexes on individual UDT fields are not yet supported (see [CASSANDRA-6382](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6382)).